# Как вывести подписи значений к диаграмме Ганта

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график, визуализация

Как можно вывести подписи значений к каждой из строчек на графике?

Пример графика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Пример](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pED4oFOuCcbZyoSuh_F-uUM7yuT6Ff0n/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100335429201323787767&rtpof=true&sd=true) датасета.

Код:

```
file2 = 'Вопрос.xlsx'
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)
df2
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15,8))
operation_lenght = df2.Duration
ax.barh(df2.Operation, df2.Duration, left=df2.Start, color=df2.Color)
ax.set_xlabel('Duration')
ax.set_ylabel('Operations')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод `ax.bar_label`, предварительно явно обозначив свой объект со столбчатой диаграммой:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15,8))
operation_lenght = df2.Duration
bars = ax.barh(df2.Operation, df2.Duration, left=df2.Start, color=df2.Color)
# ^^^ присваиваем объект эксплицитно
ax.bar_label(bars, label_type='center', labels = df2["Operation"])
# ^^^ работаем с полученным объектом с помощью метода bar_label. labels выбираете сами.

ax.set_xlabel('Duration')
ax.set_ylabel('Operations')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего там значение `Finish` справа от блоков было бы логично приписывать. Но главное сам принцип показан.